# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot fully, "p link was shut down"

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome, gui, gdm

On Boot Screen Log:

```
[ OK ] Sarted GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service....proxy server...p link was shut down.
```

OS:
Ubuntu 18.04.6  (last 32-bit)
Linux 4.15.0-176-generic
Gnome: 3.28.2

I could log in via ssh and I tried: [Ubuntu fails to boot fully, stuck in log screen "ppp link was shut down"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057300/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-fully-stuck-in-log-screen-ppp-link-was-shut-down) Solution b and then Solution a, but both didn't help.
Then I did `sudo apt purge gdm gdm3` and now I even can't login via ssh anymore. Also Alt-F2/Alt-F7 on the PC directly didn't help.

Next I tried: [Ubuntu doesn't start, with a message 'Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service... system changes.pp link was shut down'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163595/ubuntu-doesnt-start-with-a-message-started-gnome-display-manager-dispatcher?rq=1)
while reinstalling `sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop`, but it didn't help either.

CLI only would be sufficient for me as well. How can i downgrade the desktop/gnome environment? But full functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: I am confused. How does the down grading of Gnome or any DE fix the problem. Also no you can not do that.

Comment: It seems the gdm causes the problem, so the removal of the gdm and the only use of the cli could solve the problem, as i my understanding the cli does not need the gdm/gdm3 to work. What does "DE" mean?

After waiting a while, the boot process somehow continued and now I can login with ssh again, but the screen is only showing the _ bar

Comment: DE means Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want CLI only, I recommend you reinstall with [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server).

Removing gdm from your install should not affect openssh-server. So I am not sure what happened there.

If you have data on your current install, and don't want to reinstall, I recommend you use the "Advanced Options" in the GRUB boot menu, and boot in [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

When in single-user text mode you could investigate your ssh issue, or uninstall components you no longer need. Like the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

A minimal OS like ubuntu-server is less likely to have issues, and also: what GPU are you using?

Comment: `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV5 [Riva TNT2 Model 64 / Model 64 Pro] (rev 15) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Subsystem: PROLINK Microsystems Corp Pixelview RIVA TNT2 M64

Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 12

Memory at ea000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]

Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]

[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]

Capabilities: <access denied>

Kernel modules: rivafb, nvidiafb, nouveau`

(very old) do you think it is broken somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I accidentally updated to Ubuntu 18.04.6, however **16**.04.6 is the last 32-Bit version.
The 18.04.6 worked for a short time, probably until the gnome desktop manager (gdm) was updated. The other programs as ssh etc. seemed to still work.

Why i couldn't log in via ssh i still can't tell, maybe it took more time to restart due to the gdm issue and i wasn't patient enough to wait, as the gdm is started first and then the openssh-server.

I reinstalled version **16.04.6** from scratch and it works again. I had some trouble with the hdd so i can't tell if a corrupted package was also the cause of this problem. I will test the hdd soon and give update about it.